# What's the terminal command to see how network shares are connected?

Tags: terminal, network

I would like to see how certain volume shares are connected to my Mac. I'm on a Windows network and need to know if shares are connected over smb2 or cifs or afp protocol... etc... Do I need to restart my Mac each time to get an accurate reading? (cache)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the mount command from terminal:

```
mount
```

This will give a print out of everything mounted on the system and details about what protocol was used and by who.  Here's in example output:

```
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map -fstab on /Network/Servers (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /Volumes/TM Backup (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled)
//user@theShare:548/Share on /Volumes/Share (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by user)
```

Comment: Simple. Thank you. Would this differentiate from CIFS vs SMB? Or is it all the same to the Mac?

Comment: CIFS stands for Common Internet File System.  It is the standard file sharing in Windows.  Mac accesses it using the Samba protocol(SMB).

Comment: Interestingly, in Big Sur (macOS 11.6) this shows me where the share is mounted, but I cannot `ls` those directories. I can, however, use Finder to view the contents. To be super clear, `ls /Volumes/Users` yields `operation not permitted` and Finder Shift-Command-G `/Volumes/Users` shows all!

Comment: It's a security setting in System Preferences. Terminal didn't have access to "Network Volumes" under "Privacy"->"Files and Folders".

Answer (score 15):

For a more detailed listing of samba connections including the protocol in use, try:

```
smbutil statshares -a
```

Comment: this isn't working for me. I have smb on, I have a share, but when I type that command it shows no shares